# How to send events to Firebase Analytics in iMessage extension

Tags: ios, events, swift3, firebase-analytics, imessage

I've been trying to send events like when a user taps on a tableview cell to firebase analytics through my imessage app to no avail. Using

`FIRAnalytics.logEvent(withName: "\(stickerUniqueName)", parameters: nil)`

I also added `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` to my scheme

I have this setup on a regular app, it works just fine and logs the event in the xcode console so I can see it was sent. But I can't get it to show up the same for the imessage extension.

I guess what I'm eluding to is it possible to log events in an imessage extension? Is there any other service I can track button presses with on an  imessage extension?

Comment: Please describe the issue more detailed "I can't seem to get it to do the same in the imessage extension".

Comment: @shallowThought Pretty much with firebase analytics you can send events and log them in the Xcode console to see if they were successful. I have been able to achieve this in a regular  app but not in the imessage extension.

Comment: Understood. For debug reasons, Put all `Firebase` code in `willBecomeActive` in MessagesViewController. See if it works there. If not, post the whole code.

Comment: Have you tried plugging the device and view the log from the device? You can also attach XCode to the extension's process.

Comment: @AlexD Yes I did try with my phone :(

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I checked back the next day and the events showed up in Firebase analytics woot! but I still haven't manage to get the events to log in the xcode console. So problem kinda solved...

> Big take away here is that Firebase analytics does work in iMessage
>   extensions. It just takes a couple hours to show up.

Comment: That's great to hear. I couldn't find a way to turn on debug mode using the launch argument either but if you find a way, please let us know as we are interested to know too.